# Get position based on scaling factor

Tags: wpf, transform

I am going to perform transforamation on particular element. Before doing so i need to check some constraints. so am predicting the height and width of that element by using following code.

```
 double width = f.ActualWidth * Math.Abs(m.M11) + f.ActualHeight * Math.Abs(m.M21);
            double height = f.ActualHeight * Math.Abs(m.M22) + f.ActualWidth * Math.Abs(m.M12);
```

now i need position of those element also (i.e what will be the position if i perform tha transformation). Is that possible to achieve?

Comment: In case the Matrix is to be applied to the element's LayoutTransform by means of a MatrixTransform, you could get the result by the MatrixTransform's [TransformBounds](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.transform.transformbounds.aspx) method.

Comment: I need found the values before applying the transformation. if the result satisfies my requirement then only i can apply that transformation to my element.as i have posted in my query the width that i have found will be the width of the element if i applied transform, like was i need x,y co-ordinates also.

Comment: "before applying the transformation", that's what I meant. Create a MatrixTransform from the matrix and call TransformBounds on the element's rect to get the result of a possible LayoutTransform.

Comment: if you don't mind, can you please explain because i had used transform bounds also, but i dint get the result as i expected.